# How to Embed Ustream video into iOS

Tags: ios

Has anyone found a way to easily embed ustream video within a iphone or ipad app? I have sent emails to the ustream support, but no response. I really dont want to run through ffmpeg or anything.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is by just opening the embed URL (e.g. http://www.ustream.tv/embed/10638475) using a UIWebView. This will use HTTP Live Streaming on iOS.

Alternatively you can use a URL like http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/10638475/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8 to initiate an `AVPlayerItem` and use an `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` to play the stream within the app's UI (very useful if you don't want it to be full screen).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<iframe  id="UstreamIframe" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/10638475"></iframe>
```

Comment: This live stream url is issue with Google Mob Ad iOS SDK.