# Embed ustream live video in android app

Tags: android, live-streaming

Has anyone found a way to easily embed ustream live video within a android app? I have sent emails to the ustream support, but no response. I tried with webview and playerview but dint work.  There is way available to do it iOS. here is the link [How to Embed Ustream video into iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321334/how-to-embed-ustream-video-into-ios)  Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Embed using `WebView` then enable JavaScript using

> webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);