# Streaming Live Ustream video to Android App

Tags: java, android, video, embed

I have an Android app and I want to implement a feature that allows me to play a Live video from Ustream but I have no idea if this can be done using the embed code. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949755/embed-ustream-live-video-in-android-app) but it doesn't really help. 
Has anybody had luck achieving this or something similar?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please, see if they provide you a API with a "rtsp" link. (I think they do.)
Then, you must use this into your VideoView URI. It'll be something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("{YOUR RTSP LINK HERE}");

        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();      
    }

    (...)
}
```

and your layout file, main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="{yourpackageandsuch}.MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll go on a hunt for an RTSP link however I can't see anything on the video that even sounds similar to that :/