# How to broadcast video (stream) to a Ustream channel from a custom iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, html5-video

I would like to know if it is possible to embed a Ustream video streaming session in an iOS app. I am basically looking for a public SDK to publish live videos to a Ustream channel.

I have a Ustream developer account. They offer a REST API that makes it easy to embed a viewer that consumes Ustream content. But I do not see anything available to publish.

OpenTok, which seems to offer an similar video broadcasting service, has this: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Basic-Tutorial -- which looks like what I would want (see: `(void)doPublish`). But are you aware of something equivalent for Ustream channels?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321334/how-to-embed-ustream-video-into-ios

Comment: there are developer docs at http://developer.ustream.tv/data_api/docs

Comment: Hi Rachel - I did see those two links already. The stackoverflow thread talks bout how to embed a Ustream player to view a stream. The data API also seem to solve this stream consumption problem: "The Ustream APIs gives you the ability to:

Access content available on the Ustream website.
Search for people, channels and videos.
Pull down useful or interesting systems and operations information such as the most recently started show and total concurrent shows." What I a looking for is a way to **publish** a live stream (captured with the device camera) to a Ustream channel.